# How to rename a wget output, to a name inside a file(bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, wget

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat pdfs.txt`
do 

wget --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -c -O $i > `cat pdfsnaming.txt`

done
```

I'm using wget to scrape a list of pdf documents, I want to rename them the contents of the text document "pdfsnaming.txt". I know you rename a wget with- (capital O acknowledged)

```
wget-O $i > foo.tag
```

pdfsnaming.txt- around 500 names inside, some with spaces, some without; -no quote
(ex:JohnDoe) ex: John Doe)

```
nameone
nametwo
namethree
name spaced
namefour
name spaced2
```

pdfs.txt- contains urls fyi, no quotes

Error Result/downloaded file names--

> --waitretry=1

IT NAMES IT AS THE FIRST FULL-WORDED WGET TAG??

Experimentally I guess this could be done with an array? But then the issue comes along that it would be one huge array, and I'd have to add separate code to add quotes and brackets etc etc. Not to mention the Quotes has to not cause this (ex: "name" "spaced").

```
while read -a arr;
do wget --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 1 -cO 
"${arr[0]}".pdf "${arr[1]}" 
done < <(paste -d'\1' pdfsnaming.txt pdfs.txt)
```

Debugged code

Comment: You're trying to read the filenames line by line from pdfsnaming.txt?

Comment: yes, I want each wget output from the loop named the name in pdfsnaming.txt, down the list.

Comment: `paste` is the command which acts like zipping. you wanto take a look at that.

Comment: Are there spaces in the names? And how are they delimited?

Comment: yes, like, for ex. John Doe, while some are like for ex. JohnDoe

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr whats the difference between cat and paste?

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian whenever there is a tool you don't know, you should consult `man` first. it's your best bet to understand how to work on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. As I commented, you can indeed deal with it using `paste`.

```
$ cat pdfs
a
b
c
d
$ cat names
aa
b b
cccc
d d d d
```

`paste` gives you a zipped output:

```
$  paste -d'\1' pdfs names
aaa
bb b
ccccc
dd d d d
```

`-d` means delimiter, choosing `'\1'` to be delimiter because it's not printable, and therefore it's unlikely you will hit issue with it for this application.

Then the rest is routine:

```
$ IFS='\1'
$ while read -a arr; do echo pdf is "${arr[0]}", name is "${arr[1]}"; done < <(paste -d'\1' pdfs names)
pdf is a, name is aa
pdf is b, name is b b
pdf is c, name is cccc
pdf is d, name is d d d d
```

You need to set `IFS` to let `read` know your customized delimiter. You can recover by unsetting it.

```
$ unset IFS
```

Comment: "`:` is not arbitrary: this character cannot occur in file name" - it can.

Comment: @Dzienny let me fix that entirely.

Comment: @Dzienny i though `'\0'` would work but it doesn't. anyways, there are many choices among unprintable characters.

Comment: But how do you apply this with wget?

Comment: you just plug your `$i` with `${arr[0]}` and file name with `${arr[1]}`, both with quotes.

Comment: does pdf stand for pdf.txt, and name for pdfnaming.txt? pdf.txt contains the urls for wget to grab, and pdfnaming.txt contains the names

Comment: yes you just plug in your script. i cannot do wget just for testing.

Comment: is pdfs names, do  you means pdfs.txt and pdfsnaming.txt or just pdfsnaming.txt? or neither?

Comment: well, `pdfs` is `pdfs.txt` and the remaining maps. if you try my answer yourself, it's gonna be easier. i think you should try to understand how my answer works instead of asking others to give you a working piece of code.

Comment: ```#!/bin/bash
unset IFS
IFS='\1'
while read -a arr;
 do wget -c -O --waitretry=1 --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 -t 1 pdfs.txt "${arr[0]}" 
 done < <(paste -d'\1'pdfsnaming.txt)```

Comment: `pdfs names` are two parameters. you should pass in two file names.

Comment: @CaucasianMalaysian also you are missing `;` before `done`.

Comment: its wgetting, however this solution doesn't name the wget file to the name. What it does however make empty text files called those in pdfsnaming.txt